# Virtual Environment for server utilization

Tags: django, virtual-machine, utilization

I have a django app and I would like to have an experience on scaling-up my project.

http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter21/

In this document  scaling issues of django applications are explained very well but before I buy new servers I would like to try the softwares which are mentioned in the document.

Is it possible to run 4-5 virtual machines and install linux servers on each of them in my local computer and distribute database,media and source code of my application on them ?

The reason for that I would like to test the softwares like load-balancers or mysql replication tools before production enviroment.

Comment: What do you mean, is it possible? Have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not only possible but very easy.  Take a look at the Vagrant[1](http://vagrantup.com/) project.  It's a set of small programs built around creating/updating/managing virtual environments for software development.